# Creating an admin user in production on Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I deployed my Spree app to a server. Locally I can login as an admin and change things, but on the server this password and account does not work. When I go to /admin I get the message authorization failure.

I did already run bundle exec rake spree_auth:admin:create and bundle exec rake db:migrate but this does not work. Furthermore, I can also login with my e-mailaddress and password I got from the hosting company, but I can not go to the admin page.

Does anyone know how I create an admin user?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Deploying Spree doesn't (and shouldn't) copy your database from development to production.

So your development admin user doesn't exist on the production database.

SSH into your production server and try:

```
rake spree_auth:admin:create
```

**Update:**

Do this in **/data/spree/current**

Comment: Thanks. I will try that this evening. In which folder on the server should I run this command? Public, shared, or another one?

Comment: There it says: "rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter"

Comment: Doing: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate helped.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: in production `rake spree_auth:admin:create` return error but `RAILS_ENV=production rake spree_auth:admin:create` works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can run the DB seeds, which include the admin user:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:seed
```

If you also want to add sample data, you can run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```